# How can I fix these OpenGL linking problems in MinGW?

Tags: opengl, mingw, linker-errors

I have a project that I have been coding on OS X that I am now trying to get building on Windows. I have set up MinGW, created a makefile, and after a good deal of finagling everything compiles, however when it gets to the linker step a great number of errors occur along the lines of:

```
SourceFile.cpp:(.text+0x1809): undefined reference to 'glEnable@4'
```

The linker command, omitting all the source.o names is fairly straightforward:

```
g++ -lglu32 -lopengl32
```

I have also tried with the link order switched, and with the full path to the .a files included, all give me the same results. Using the _STDCALL_SUPPORTED and _M_IX86 macros in the compiler step has not made any difference.

In case it's relevant, I am using GLee, which I am building directly into my program (though I also tried with glew, and got the same results).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution was maddeningly simple, for reasons I do not fully understand the `-lglu32 -lopengl32` had to be on the right side of the list of .o files instead of the left in the command.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons are simple.  As things link, for a link line that has things in this order:
A B C D

B resolves externals in A, C resolves externals in A and B, and so forth.  If there are externals in D that need to be resolved by A, you need to include A after D... which IIRC, you can get away by adding A again...

A B C D A